# meteor array $addToSet not adding any items

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I'm trying to add instruments to a Profiles collection in meteor using $addToSet.  The code works in mongo, but will not work in the meteor methods call.  I am able to update all other fields without any issues using $set, so I know that this is finding the correct user.

```
updateInstruments(instruments) {
if (!this.userId) {
  throw new Meteor.Error('not-logged-in',
    'Must be logged in to update last name.');
}

check(instruments, String);

if (instruments.length === 0) {
  throw Meteor.Error('instruments-required', 'Must provide at least one instrument.');
}

let instrArray = instruments.split(',');
instrArray.forEach(function(instrument){
  instrument = instrument.trim();
  Profiles.update({ userId: this.userId }, { $addToSet: { instruments: instrument } });
});
```

},

I have even tried:

```
Profiles.update({ userId: this.userId }, { $addToSet: { instruments: {$each: [instrument] } }});
```

as well as:

```
Profiles.update({ userId: this.userId }, { $addToSet: { instruments: [instrument]  }});
```

I have also tried $push and nothing happened there as well.  Is there some sort of bug within meteor?  Is there some other setting I need to configure to allow the updating of arrays?

UPDATE: 
Per request, here's the client code:

```
updateInstruments() {
   if (_.isEmpty(this.data.instruments)) return;
      var self = this;
      let instruments = this.data.instruments;
      this.callMethod('updateInstruments', instruments, (err) => {
         if (err) return this.handleError(err);
      });
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: can you please include your client side code too? this is probably a problem caused by how you pass 'instruments' from client side and split, trim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the issue.  I forgot that the scope of 'this' changes in the inline 'instrArray.forEach' function, making this.userId 'undefined'. The Profiles collection was unable to find the record.  I changed the following code:

```
let instrArray = instruments.split(',');
instrArray.forEach(function(instrument){
  instrument = instrument.trim();
  Profiles.update({ userId: this.userId }, { $addToSet: { instruments: instrument } });
});
```

to:

```
let userId = this.userId;
let instrArray = instruments.split(',');
instrArray.forEach(function(instrument){
    instrument = instrument.trim();
    Profiles.update({ userId: userId }, { $addToSet: { instruments: instrument }     });
});
```

Thanks everyone for looking over my code!

Answer (score 0):

Your query seems fine to me. As long as you are doing that on server, you don't need to configure anything. Not a bug in Meteor.